# How to include images and videos in RSS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rss

Do you know if it is possible to show images and videos in RSS? I've always shown text and links and i would like to know how can media be inserted in RSS feed.
I use ASPNET.MVC3

Comment: you can definitely include it; how it will appear to the user depends on what they are using to consume the feed. images, video, etc show up fine in google reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just include markup like you would for a webpage. Here is an example feed from npr.org music that includes images and videos.

http://www.npr.org/rss/rss.php?id=15709577